# jQuery blur event fires only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, onblur

I'm making a script to manage a shopping cart and I wanted to attach a blur event to the input field where you can change the quantity of a product.

The problem is the event only fires once. After that I have to refresh the page to enable it again.

Right now I have this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input",".fila_producto").each(function() {
        $(this).on('focusout', {param: $(this).parent().parent().attr('id')}, updateCantidadProducto);
    });
});
```

In the script I use as a parameter the ID of the row and I'm using the input to check its value.

The function to make the request is this one:

```
function updateCantidadProducto(event){
    var id = event.data.param;
    var cantidad = $(this).val();

    var datos = {   
        "modify" : true,
        "identificador" : id,
        "cantidad": cantidad
    };

    $.ajax({
        data: datos,
        url: 'carrito.php',
        type: 'post',
        success: function(response){
            $("#aside").replaceWith(response);
        }
    }); 

}
```

It works nice the first time but then the event doesn't work. Any suggestions on how bad I made this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you're asking.

```
(function($){
    $(document).on('blur',
                  'input,.fila_producto',
                  {param: $(this).parent().parent().attr('id')},
                   updateCantidadProducto
                  );
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: It worked, just had to put the param part inside the handler (don't know exactly why I didn't put it earlier). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

the fail proof syntax for binding events to elements on the dom (whether they are new elements or pre-existing elements) is

```
$(document).on('focusout', '.fila_producto', function() {
   // do stuff here
});
```

`$(document)` can also be a more specific selector that has the `.fila_producto` class in it (but make sure that whatever selector you use is pre-existing on the dom, not an added element).  hope this helps!